# Size issue while creating external table in BigQuery on GCS in AVRO format

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, avro

I am trying to create an external table in BigQuery but I am getting the following exception while doing so:

```
Error while reading table: nginx_ext_table, error message: Total Avro data size exceeds max allowed size. Total size is at least: 13195947263283. Max allowed size is: 13194139533312.
```

is there any limit on table/dataset size in BigQuery?

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried to create the table from the webUI? This doesn't look to be directly related to `BigQuery` per this link https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources

Comment: @Tamir Klein Yes, I did try with Web UI but getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting the "[Maximum size per load job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs)" limit which is 15 TB across all input files for CSV, JSON, Avro, Parquet, and ORC. Therefore, try lowering the size of your files to avoid hitting this limit.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery have quotas for all type of operation, import job/external data source has a 15TB restriction.

```
The limits for external data sources are the same as the limits for load jobs, as described in the Load jobs section on the quotas and limits page
```

More details refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources#external_data_source_quotas)

```
Maximum size per load job — 15 TB across all input files for CSV, JSON, Avro, Parquet, and ORC
```

Comment: Actually, I am not importing/loading data into BigQuery rather creating an external table on GCS path where data is residing in AVRO format.